# Ionic ngFor duplicating items when i go from another page back to the original page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I’m having troubles with my code duplicating items with ngFor when i go from one page to back to its own page. When the code runs first time it is fine and does what i need it to do, but when i go from one tab back to the original tab with the ngFor it duplicates the items.

TS Code;

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
 export class HomePage {
 selection: any[];
 titles: any[];
 show: boolean = false;

 constructor(private modalCtrl: ModalController,
          private photoService: PhotoService) {}

ionViewWillEnter() {
this.titles = this.photoService.getTitle();
this.selection = this.photoService.getPhotoRoll();
if(this.titles.length > 0) {
  this.show = true;
}
console.log(this.selection);
}

onPlaySlide(index: number) {
const num = { number: index }
console.log(index);
const modal = this.modalCtrl.create(SlidePage, num);
modal.present();
}

}
```

HTML code;

```
<ion-list *ngIf="show">
  <ion-item-sliding
    *ngFor="let select of selection; let i = index">
    <ion-item (click)="onPlaySlide(i)">
        <ion-thumbnail item-start>
          <img [src]="select.img">
        </ion-thumbnail>
        <h2 *ngFor="let title of titles">{{ title }}</h2>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item-options>
      <button 
        ion-button 
        color="danger"
        (click)="onRemoveFromPhotoRoll(select)">
        <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>
        Delete
      </button>
    </ion-item-options>
  </ion-item-sliding>
</ion-list>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: try implementing OnInit and creating a method called ngOnInit(). remove the getTitle() service method from the current method and put it inside of your ngOnInit() method and let me know if that works.

Comment: what is `console.log(this.selection);` printing when you are back to the page?

Comment: Can you show your code for `photoService.getTitle()` and `photoService.getPhotoRoll()`?

Comment: @Aragorn and BRass thank you for your help. My code in my service was doing the duplication.

Answer (score 0):

Put your service call in view did load :

```
ionViewDidLoad{
this.titles = this.photoService.getTitle();
this.selection = this.photoService.getPhotoRoll();
if(this.titles.length > 0) {
  this.show = true;
}
console.log(this.selection);

}
```